# Why are my images not responsive (on iPhone?)

Tags: css, responsive

I use Maya Theme but for some reason my images are not responsive on the homepage when i use it on the phone. Can anyone please tell me why they display full size?

http://www.brycemckenzie.co.uk

Thanks

```
<div class="borderpattern" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>
<h3 style="text-align: center; padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 25px;">Bryce McKenzie: Interior Design Edinburgh provides a comprehensive design and project management service for residential and commercial projects.</h3>
<div class="borderpattern" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 25px;"></div>
<div id="imagemenu">
<div class="imagemenu-item-large"><a href="bryce-mckenzie-upholstered-furniture"><img class="wp-image-103 alignleft" src="http://www.brycemckenzie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/productsandservices.jpg" alt="Products And Services" width="100%" height="auto"/></a></div>
<div class="imagemenu-item-large"><a href="drapery"><img class="alignright wp-image-102" src="http://www.brycemckenzie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/portfolio4.jpg" alt="Portfolio" width="100%" height="auto"/></a></div>
<div class="clear" style="height: 30px;"></div>
<div class="imagemenu-item-small"><a href="about/showroom"><img class="size-full wp-image-103 alignleft" src="http://www.brycemckenzie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/aboutus1.jpg" alt="About Us"/></a></div>
<div class="imagemenu-item-small"><a href="featured-artists/alison-rollo-sculptor"><img class="size-full wp-image-103 alignleft" src="http://www.brycemckenzie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/featuredartists.jpg" alt="Featured Artists"/></a></div>
<div class="imagemenu-item-small"><a href="press"><img class="size-full wp-image-103 alignleft" src="http://www.brycemckenzie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/press.jpg" alt="Press"/></a></div>
<div class="imagemenu-item-small"><a href="contact"><img class="size-full wp-image-103 alignleft" src="http://www.brycemckenzie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/contactus.jpg" alt="Contact Us" /></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are definining static dimensions in your CSS: `.imagemenu-item-large a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

1. The original size of your images is not large enough. Your site has a breakpoint set at 960px (when the images stack vertically), but the images are only 425px in width. One solution is to upload larger images. Or, it may be a CMS is resizing the images. If this is the case you'll need to configure the CMS to save larger images. While we can fix this issue, the images will be stretched and become pixelated.
2. There is some CSS preventing the image (or its parent rather) from extending to the full width. Add the following to the end of your `custom.css` file:

   ```
   @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
     .imagemenu-item-large {
       float: none;
     }

     .imagemenu-item-large a {
       width: 100%;
     }
   }
   ```

What is this doing? The `@media` is applying the CSS only when the screen is smaller than 960px in width. We're then undoing some CSS set previously in `custom.css` to allow the image's parent container to go full-width, then the `a` tag around the image to go full-width, allowing the image to go full-width.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this for you by doing this:
`.imagemenu-item-large a{width: auto;}`

Remeber to add this to a media query.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
.imagemenu-item-large a {
    display: block;
    width: 425px;
    height: 299px;
}
```

Which is causing the image to fill to the size of the `href` because of the `block` element. If you remove the `display: block` and then add something like this to your images:

```
.yourimageclass {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Then they will show how you want. I wasn't sure what class name you wanted to use so you will have to change that. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The images are a fixed width. Try this:

```
@media and (max-width: 767px) {
  .imagemenu-item-large {
    width: 324px;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```